# How to use Ajax within Sonata Admin forms?

Tags: ajax, symfony, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

I have a Merchant entity with the following fields and associations:-

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="merchants")
 */
public $categories;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="merchants")
 */
public $tags;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="merchants")
 */
protected $primaryCategory;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="merchants")
 */
protected $primaryTag;
```

The Tags and Categories also have a ManyToMany mapping. 
So we have Tag_Category, Merchant_Tag, Merchant_Category mapping tables.

Now I want to perform some ajax on these fields.

I want to allow the user to select the Primary Tag first. On the basis of the Primary Tag, ajax refresh the categories to only those which belong to this Tag and some more operations.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I was able to make this work a few months back. While what a.aitboudad has shared is accurate. There are a few gotcha's that first timers with Symfony/Sonata might face.

Here are the steps.

**1> Extend Sonata CRUD's `edit.html.twig` / `base_edit.html.twig` .** 
For simplicity, I'll use only the latter. 
Copy `vendor/bundles/Sonata/AdminBundle/Resources/views/CRUD/base_edit.html.twig` into the views folder corresponding to the MerchantAdminController - `YourBundle/Resources/views/Merchant/base_edit.html.twig`

**2> We need to tell our MerchantAdmin class to use this template.** So we override SonataAdmin's `getEditTemplate` method like this:

```
public function getEditTemplate()
{
    return 'YourBundle:Merchant:base_edit.html.twig';
}
```

**3>** Next we need to **code the Ajax functionality** in our `base_edit.html.twig` . Standard Ajax comprises of the following:

**3.1>** -- Create an Action in the controller for the Ajax request
We primarily want to get a list of category IDs corresponding to a particular tag. But most likely you are just using Sonata's CRUD Controller.

Define your MerchantAdminController which extends CRUDController

```
<?php

namespace GD\AdminBundle\Controller;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController as Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use GD\AdminBundle\Entity\Merchant;

class MerchantAdminController extends Controller
{

}
```

**3.2>** -- Tell your Admin service to use this newly created controller instead of the default CRUDController by defining it in `YourBundle/Resources/config/services.yml`

```
gd_admin.merchant:
        class: %gd_admin.merchant.class%
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: gd_merchant, label: Merchants }
        arguments: [null, GD\AdminBundle\Entity\Merchant, GDAdminBundle:MerchantAdmin]
```

Notice that the 3rd argument is the name of your controller. By default it would have been null.

**3.3>** -- Create an Action named `getCategoryOptionsFromTagAction` in your controller. Your Ajax call will be to this Action.

```
// route - get_categories_from_tag
public function getCategoryOptionsFromTagAction($tagId)
    {   
        $html = ""; // HTML as response
        $tag = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('YourBundle:Tag')
            ->find($tagId);

        $categories = $tag->getCategories();

        foreach($categories as $cat){
            $html .= '<option value="'.$cat->getId().'" >'.$cat->getName().'</option>';
        }

        return new Response($html, 200);
    }
```

**3.4>** -- Create the corresponding route in `app/config/routing.yml`. Remember to expose your route if you are using the FOSJsRoutingBundle (else you'll have to hardcode which is not a good idea).

```
get_categories_from_tag:
    pattern: /{_locale}/admin/gd/admin/merchant/get-categories-from-tag/{tagId}
    defaults: {_controller: GDAdminBundle:MerchantAdmin:getCategoryOptionsFromTag}
    options:
        expose: true
```

**3.5>** -- Make the Ajax Request and use the response

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
            var primaryTag = $("#{{ admin.uniqId }}_primaryTag");
            primaryTag.change(updateCategories()); // Bind the function to updateCategories
            primaryTag.change(); // Manual trigger to update categories in Document load.

            function updateCategories(){
                return function () {
                    var tagId = $("#{{ admin.uniqId }}_primaryTag option:selected").val();
                    var primaryCategory = $("#{{ admin.uniqId }}_primaryCategory");
                    primaryCategory.empty();
                    primaryCategory.trigger("liszt:updated");
                    var locale = '{{ app.request.get('_locale') }}';

                    var objectId = '{{ admin.id(object) }}'

                    var url = Routing.generate('get_categories_from_tag', { '_locale': locale, 'tagId': tagId, _sonata_admin: 'gd_admin.merchant', id: objectId });
                    $.post(url, { tagId: tagId }, function(data){
                        primaryCategory.empty().append(data);
                        primaryCategory.trigger("liszt:updated");
                    },"text");

                    primaryCategory.val("option:first").attr("selected", true);
                };
            }
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

***Gotcha 1:*** How to get the Unique ID that is appended to all Sonata elements

***Solution:*** Use the admin variable which will give you access to all the Admin Class's properties including uniqId. See code on how to use it.

***Gotcha 2:*** How to get the Router in your JS.

***Solution:*** By default Symfony2 Routing doesn't work in JS. You need to use a bundle called FOSJSRouting (explained above) and expose the route. This will give you access to the Router object within your JS too.

I have modified my solution slightly to make this example clearer. If you notice anything wrong, please feel free to comment.

Comment: Great answer, great detail, nice one! One question - why did you need to use the FOSJSRouting stuff in your ajax call? Would it not have been just as easy to pass the tagId as a part of the ajax post request? That way you can avoid loading the extra bundle

Comment: Thanks dude, FOSJSRouting is to access the Router object (Routing.generate(...)) to generate the path for the route. If it were a plain PHP project we'd just give the filename - categories_from_tag.php. But here we need to invoke an action within a controller.

Comment: The way I did this was to add the route in my Admin class (TagAdmin): `$collection->add('addToGroup', $this->getRouterIdParameter().'/addToGroup');`, use this route for the ajax url like: `url: '{{ admin.generateUrl('addToGroup', {'id': object.id}) }}',` with the extra data parameter in the ajax definition: `data: 'group='+$(this).prevAll('.group-id').val(),`

Comment: Very useful ! Were you able to filter your categories at loading time for an existing Merchant ?

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY I'm not sure, but I am positive that categories could have been filtered. I don't have access to the code anymore, else would have checked and responded.

Comment: I don't think using ``MerchantAdmin::getEditTemplate()`` works any more. I had to change this to ``MerchantAdmin::getTemplate($name)`` and then return my custom template when ``$name === 'edit'``

Comment: @Amit Do you have an idea how to get the uniqid of the parent admin class when being inside the script template as described in my issue? https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle/issues/378

Comment: I got this successfully done for ajax, but the `entity` field always get the validation error `This value is not valid.` upon form submission. The correct way could be http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-submitted-data

Comment: @lopsided can you please elaborate on the part where you pass the tagId as part as the ajax post request? `data: 'group='+$(this).prevAll('.group-id').val(),` I don't understand what is going on here. Please?

Answer (score 4):

At step 1 of Amit and Lumbendil answer you should change

```
{% extends base_template %}
```

into

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig' %}
```

if you get an error like

```
Unable to find template "" in YourBundle:YourObject:base_edit.html.twig at line 34.
```

Answer (score 4):

Very detailed post, just to update the way of override and use the *edit* template in the Admin class.
Now, you should do it this way:

```
// src/AppBundle/Admin/EntityAdmin.php  

class EntityAdmin extends Admin
{  
    public function getTemplate($name)
    {
        if ( $name == "edit" ) 
        {
            // template 'base_edit.html.twig' placed in app/Resources/views/Entity
            return 'Entity/base_edit.html.twig' ;
        }
        return parent::getTemplate($name);
    }
}
```

Or inject it in the service definition used the [provided method](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/templates.html#configuring-templates), to keep the Admin class as cleaner as possible:

```
// app/config/services.yml  

app.admin.entity:
    class: AppBundle\Admin\EntityAdmin
    arguments: [~, AppBundle\Entity\Entity, ~]
    tags:
        - {name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Group", label: "Label"}
    calls:
        - [ setTemplate, [edit, Entity/base_edit.html.twig]]
```

Answer (score 2):

in the block javascripts, you have to change `"liszt:updated"` to `"chosen:updated"`

hope it helps someone ;)

Comment: Welcome to SO :) You should avoid asking a new question inside an answer. Either use comments for that or open a new question.