# How to create dynamics forms fields based on another form field in sonata admin?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

How can i update the content of a specific form field inside an admin interface from Sonata Admin based on another form field ?

An example : i have an entity Contract ManyToOne Client, Users ManyToOne Client, Users ManyToOne Product. When i choose a Contract in form (select input) i want my product select updated with only related products. I know how to create a custom query but not how to bind it via ajax.

I could do it without any problem outside sonata admin but don't know how inside it.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118868/how-to-use-ajax-within-sonata-admin-forms?rq=1

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This is exactly what i've been looking for :)

Comment: I think your answer lies here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246192/correct-way-to-use-formevents-to-customise-fields-in-sonataadmin

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do it (or atleast I still haven't found a way to do it).

They best way to do it (or how I do it) is to overwrite the view, create your own custom form and work with ajax from there.

Comment: did you have an example of how achieving this in sonata ?