# Correct way to use FormEvents to customise fields in SonataAdmin

Tags: forms, symfony, sonata-admin

I have a Sonata Admin class with some form fields in it, but I'd like to use the `FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA` event to dynamically add another form field based on the bound data.

However, I'm running into several problems:

1) The only way I can find to add the form field to the correct 'formGroup' in the admin is by adding the new field twice (once via the formMapper and once via the form itself)... this seems very wrong and I cannot control where in the formGroup it appears.

2) The added element doesn't seem to know that it has a connected Admin (probably because it is added using `Form::add()`). This means, amongst other things, that it renders differently to the other fields in the form since it triggers the `{% if sonata_admin is not defined or not sonata_admin_enabled or not sonata_admin.field_description %}` condition in `form_admin_fields.html.twig`

So, this leads me to believe that I'm doing this all wrong and there must be a better way.

So...

**What is the correct way to use a FormEvent to add a field to a form group, ideally in a preferred position within that group, when using SonataAdmin?**

Here's some code, FWIW...

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $admin = $this;
    $formMapper->getFormBuilder()->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use ($admin, $formMapper) {
        $subject = $event->getData();

        // do something fancy with $subject
        $formOptions = array(/* some cool stuff*/);

        // If I don't add the field with the $formMapper then the new field doesn't appear on the rendered form
        $formMapper
            ->with('MyFormGroup')
                ->add('foo', null, $formOptions)
            ->end()
        ;

        // If I don't add the field with Form::add() then I get a Twig Exception: 
        // Key "foo" for array with keys "..." does not exist in my_form_template.html.twig at line xx
        $event
            ->getForm()
            ->add('foo', null, $formOptions)
        ;
    });

    $formMapper
        ->with('MyFormGroup')
            ->add('fieldOne')
            ->add('fieldTwo')
        ->end()
    ;
}
```

The aim is to add the new `foo` field between `fieldOne` and `fieldTwo` in `MyFormGroup`.

---

Edit: here's what I came up with with the help of Cassiano's answer

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $builder = $formMapper->getFormBuilder();
    $ff = $builder->getFormFactory();
    $admin = $this;
    $formMapper->getFormBuilder()->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use ($ff, $admin) {
        $subject = $event->getData();

        // do something fancy with $subject
        $formOptions = array(
            'auto_initialize'       => false,
            'class'                 => 'My\ProjectBundle\Entity\MyEntity',
            /* some cool stuff*/
        );

        $event->getForm()->add($ff->createNamed('foo', 'entity', null, $formOptions));
    });

    $formMapper
        ->with('MyFormGroup')
            ->add('fieldOne')
            ->add('foo')  // adding it here gets the field in the right place, it's then redefined by the event code
            ->add('fieldTwo')
        ->end()
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No time here for a long answer, I will paste a piece of code and I don't know if fits exactly in your case, in my it's part of multi dependent selects (country, state, city, neighbor).

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper->add('myfield');

    $builder = $formMapper->getFormBuilder();
    $ff = $builder->getFormFactory();
    $func = function (FormEvent $e) use ($ff) {
        $form = $e->getForm();
        if ($form->has('myfield')) {
            $form->remove('myfield');
        }
        $form->add($ff->createNamed('myfield', 'entity', null, array(
            'class' => '...',
            'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control'),
            'auto_initialize' => false,
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) use ($pais) {
                $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('estado');
                if ($pais instanceof ...) {
                    $qb = $qb->where('myfield.other = :other')
                            ->setParameter('other', $other);
                } elseif(is_numeric($other)) {
                    $qb = $qb->where('myfield.other = :other_id')
                            ->setParameter('other_id', $other);
                }
                return $qb;
            }
        )));
    };
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, $func);
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_BIND, $func);
}
```

Comment: That seems to have done the trick - thank you! Will update the question above to show the code used for future travellers in these parts.

Comment: Hello @Cassiano, @Caponica, I have the problem. When add a $form->add($ff->createName('foto.messages'),I get this erros: `The name "foto.messages" contains illegal characters. Names should start with a letter, digit or underscore and only contain letters, digits, numbers, underscores ("_"), hyphens ("-") and colons (":").`

Comment: SOrry @webyseo can't help you only with this description, maybe you can open a new issue at Stackoverflow so we can have more details to answer you.