# how to create an ajax-driven auto-complete field in a sonata admin form in symfony?

Tags: ajax, symfony

I have a form generated with the sonata admin bundle. I want to enable a live search tip for my user on an input field. The proposition should come from a category table in the DB.

For example,  if I have a field called company, when a user writes "a", I should suggest all companies whose name contains "a".

Comment: Take a look at the detailed answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118868/how-to-use-ajax-within-sonata-admin-forms

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery Autocomplete. On server side create controller action that will return suggestions through AJAX.
See example - http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp