# how to implement onchange ajax request in sonata admin bundle Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-2.3, cascadingdropdown

I want to implement onchange ajax request in sonata admin bundle in Symfony2.I want to create a cascading dropdown.if i select option from a drop down then according to the value of the dropdown, the next dropdown will automatically populate the value.

Any idea will be appreciated ..

Comment: an answer is available here .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118868/how-to-use-ajax-within-sonata-admin-forms

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to override `standard_layout.html.twig` layout template and load your custom JS file.

Note: Maybe you just have to override the CRUD edit template and not all the layout. Create the file and specify it in your SonataAdminBundle configuration:

```
sonata_admin:
    templates:
        edit: YourCustomBundle:CRUD:edit.html.twig
```

Then, override the javascript block to add your JS file:

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/mycustombundle/myfile.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Finally, you just have to add a listener on your first dropdown field and make an AJAX request (when your selected value changed) that will point on a custom controller and return your second dropdown values.

I think this should be ok.