# SonataAdminBundle filter while typing?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-2.3

Can the DatagridFilter update results as fields are selected/entered using SonataAdminBundle?

Comment: By default I think not, but maybe if you modify the filter type (your custom) and extend the twig block for that field you can implement it. I'll look in the net for an already done working code (if I don't come back is because I had no success)

Comment: Fast answer: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118868/how-to-use-ajax-within-sonata-admin-forms