# SonataAdmin bundle linked fields (cascading select)

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I am trying to create linked drop down using sonata admin bundle.

There are

**product**

**product_categories** (many to many with product)

**product_features** (linked with product_categories) (Cardinality: many to many with product and many to one with category i.e. a category can have many features but a feature is link with one category)

Everything is working fine and one multi select enabled combo(for categories) field and another group of check boxes(for product_features) field are being displayed using this

In product entry form:

```
  protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper            
    ->add('category', 'sonata_type_model', array('required' => false, 'expanded' => false, 'multiple' => true, 'label' => 'Choose your categories'))
   ->add('features', 'sonata_type_model', array('required' => false, 'expanded' => true, 'multiple' => true, 'label' => 'Choose Features'))
```

**But what I want is when I select value in first combo i.e. categories, the second list of checkboxes i.e. features should be dynamically loaded accordingly (only features linked with that category)**

As the first select box is multi select enabled it will be even better is second list is cumulative     i.e when category 1 is selected shows features related to category1
then when category 2 is selected(with 1 also selected) it shows features linked with cat 1 and cat 2

How can I do it?

I have been googing and only good answer I found was this 2 years old solution which seems quite long and bit old. Are there any other solutions? Things must have changed in last 2 years as several versions of sonata-admin were released during that time.

[How to use Ajax within Sonata Admin forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118868/how-to-use-ajax-within-sonata-admin-forms)

Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any ways i finally solved the problem myself.The question earn me a tumbleweed badge however If any body needs it can ping me.

Comment: hi, how did you resolved this issue, thanks

Comment: @TheGooooogle Would be nice to know how you handled this case.

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of stuggle with this, but I think I came out with a practicable workaround. Hope this saved someone time in the future.

My case is: I have multiple `Company` entities with `1` to `n` `ContactPerson` entities. When I create a new `Job`, I have to select the `Company` and then I want to filter the list of `ContactPerson`s by the selected company. As you can see, its working. Depending on the selected `Company` the matching list if `ContactPerson`s is loaded:

[image: Filter screenshot 1]
[image: Filter screenshot 2]

So get this working, I just disabled the `mapping` flag for `Customer` and `ContactPerson` to map the data by myself in `postPersist` and `postUpdate` in my admin class (extends `BaseAdmin`).

Then I use a `sonata_type_choice_field_mask` for all my `Company` entities. I build a data-array by myself. After that, I add a prefiltered (by passing a matching filter) `ContactPerson` dropdown using the type `sonata_type_model`.

This is working very well - but of course, it will fail if you have thousands of companies and customers. In my case this will not happed so this is a practicable solution.

Code (removed unnecessary stuff):

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Admin;

use AppBundle\Entity\Customer;
use AppBundle\Entity\Job;
use AppBundle\Form\Types;
use AppBundle\Repository\CustomerRepository;
use AppBundle\Service\EntityManager;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\RouteCollection;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;

class JobAdmin extends BaseAdmin
{
    const CONTACT_PERSON_DROPDOWN_PREFIX = 'contactPersons';

    /**
     * @param Job $job
     * @return null|string
     */
    protected function getPreselectedCustomerId(Job $job)
    {
        if ($job) {
            $customer = $job->getCustomer();

            if ($customer) {
                $customerId = $customer->getId();

                return $customerId;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
     */
    protected function getEnabledCustomers()
    {
        $customerRepository = $this->getCustomerRepository();
        $customers          = $customerRepository->findByEnabled();

        return $customers;
    }

    /**
     * @param $enabledCustomers
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getFilterMap($enabledCustomers)
    {
        $filterMap = [];

        /**
         * @var $customer Customer
         */
        foreach ($enabledCustomers as $customer) {
            $customerId             = $customer->getId();
            $fieldName              = self::CONTACT_PERSON_DROPDOWN_PREFIX . $customerId;
            $filterMap[$customerId] = [$fieldName];
        }

        return $filterMap;
    }

    /**
     * @param $enabledCustomers
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getCustomerDropDown($enabledCustomers)
    {
        $customerDropDown = [];

        /**
         * @var $customer Customer
         */
        foreach ($enabledCustomers as $customer) {
            $customerId              = $customer->getId();
            $name                    = $customer->getName();
            $customerDropDown[$name] = $customerId;
        }

        return $customerDropDown;
    }

    /**
     * @param Customer $customer
     * @return \Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder
     */
    protected function getFilterQueryForCustomer(Customer $customer)
    {
        $entityManager      = $this->getEntityManager();
        $contactPersonQuery = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder('cp')
            ->select('cp')
            ->from('AppBundle:ContactPerson', 'cp')
            ->where('cp.customer = :customer')
            ->setParameter('customer', $customer)
            ->orderBy('cp.name', 'ASC')
        ;

        return $contactPersonQuery;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormMapper $formMapper
     */
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $job              = $this->getSubject();
        $enabledCustomers = $this->getEnabledCustomers();
        $filterMap        = $this->getFilterMap($enabledCustomers);
        $customerDropDown = $this->getCustomerDropDown($enabledCustomers);
        $preselectedId    = $this->getPreselectedCustomerId($job);

        $formMapper
            ->tab('BaseData')
                ->with('JobData')
                    ->add('customer', 'sonata_type_choice_field_mask', array(
                        'choices'      => $customerDropDown,
                        'data'         => $preselectedId,
                        'map'          => $filterMap,
                        'by_reference' => false,
                        'required'     => true,
                        'mapped'       => false,
                        )
                    )
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ;

        /**
         * @var $customer Customer
         */
        foreach ($enabledCustomers as $customer) {
            $customerId  = $customer->getId();
            $fieldName   = self::CONTACT_PERSON_DROPDOWN_PREFIX . $customerId;
            $filterQuery = $this->getFilterQueryForCustomer($customer);

            $formMapper
                ->tab('BaseData')
                    ->with('JobData')
                        ->add($fieldName, 'sonata_type_model', array(
                            'class'  => 'AppBundle\Entity\ContactPerson',
                            'query'  => $filterQuery,
                            'mapped' => false,
                            'label'  => 'Contact Person'
                        ))
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ;
        }

        $formMapper
            ->tab('BaseData')
                ->with('JobData')
                    ->add('name')
                    // Add more fields
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param EntityManager $entityManager
     * @return \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
     */
    protected function getCustomerRepository(EntityManager $entityManager = null)
    {
        if (!$entityManager) {
            $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();
        }

        $customerRepository = $entityManager->getRepository(Customer::class);

        return $customerRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @return EntityManager
     */
    protected function getEntityManager()
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();

        return $entityManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param Job $job
     */
    protected function mapUnmappedFields (Job $job)
    {
        $customerId = $this->getForm()->get('customer')->getData();

        if ($customerId)
        {
            $entityManager      = $this->getEntityManager();
            $contactPerson      = $this->getForm()->get(self::CONTACT_PERSON_DROPDOWN_PREFIX.$customerId)->getData();
            $customerRepository = $this->getCustomerRepository($entityManager);
            $customer           = $customerRepository->findById($customerId);

            if ($contactPerson) {
                $job->setContactPerson($contactPerson);
            }

            if ($customer) {
                $job->setCustomer($customer);
            }

            $entityManager->persist($job);
            $entityManager->flush($job);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $object
     */
    public function postPersist($object)
    {
        $this->mapUnmappedFields($object);

        parent::postPersist($object);
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $object
     */
    public function postUpdate($object)
    {
        $this->mapUnmappedFields($object);

        parent::postUpdate($object);
    }
}
```