# Sonata Admin Bundle - Entity Constraint on Selection

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

I am working with Sonata Admin Bundle, and have a question about constraining a pull down selector when Creating a new entry (Entity) via the admin.

The form has a selector for publisher_id and for publisher_subaccount_id.

Currently the pull down selection for publisher_subaccount_id shows all values for publisher_subaccount_id - I'm trying to constrain it to just the values of publisher_subaccount_id that are from the publisher_id already selected. Here is what the configure form fields looks like:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('publisher_id', 'entity', array('class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Publisher','property' => 'id'))
        ->add('publisher_subaccount_id', 'entity', array('class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\PublisherSubaccount','property' => 'id'))
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help or point in the right direction.

Comment: You need create a custom field or edit the template and using ajax or javascript to change values depending on Publisher selected.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10783664/2209876